# Resize image to fit into div

Tags: html, css

All my searches tell me to make the `img {max-height: 100%}` but that doesn't seem to have any effect. 
I don't understand if I've set the height of the parent container (`earth-block`), why setting the img height won't constrict the image to that size.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opKFa.png)

```css
.earth-block {
    height: 200px;
}

.earth-block img{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
            <div class="wrapper">
<div class="earth-block"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZj1KyXPz468xvFWikAXA-dPkMu14q-XuB3dKKl9LF6Bl4SO-oTw&s" alt="earth"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this ll help you out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.earth-block {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
}

.earth-block img{
    flex-grow: 100;
    object-fit: none;
    object-position: center; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="earth">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="earth-block"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/20/18/35/sunrise-1756274__340.jpg" alt="earth"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but that only made the image larger, and it still doesn't fit into the div

Comment: it fits bro. you can change the properties of the div to whatever you want to and the image ll fit for sure. i have tested it

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining it correctly. In mine, it only "fits" in that it cuts off whatever doesn't fit into the div. That's not what I want, I want the entire image to be resized so that the entire image fits into the div. With your example, if I resize the div it only shows more of the image, but the image doesn't "fit" into the div.

Comment: I used your code with a more "vertical" image and the image isn't fitting into the div. Increasing the div size will show more of the image but it's not fitting in the sense I want: https://codepen.io/El_Escandalo/pen/KKdNNxb

Comment: play a bit with the code. you can get hints out of it like it worked with horiontal images. you wont get adjact soluctions for such problems SO. if it helped you even a bit consider upvoting at least :)

Comment: Thanks I'll mess around with it. I tried upvoting it but I'm so new that my upvotes don't count yet. But I appreciate the help